# What are these cache HikariCP datasource properties

Tags: connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

HikariCP's [documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#rocket-initialization) provides these properties, namely **cachePrepStmts**, **prepStmtCacheSize** and **prepStmtCacheSqlLimit**.
But I was unable to find anywhere what they exactly mean and what are the units of the last 2 properties. Their names give some hint that they are associated with caching and prepare statements but I am still confused.

What exactly does *prepStmtCacheSize* mean and what is the unit for 250? Is it KB or MB or something else?
And absolutely no clue on what does *prepStmtCacheSqlLimit* mean and again what is the unit of 2048?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This are **specific** [MySQL Configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration)

> *prepStmtCacheSize*
> This sets the number of prepared statements that the MySQL driver will cache per connection. The default is a conservative 25. We recommend setting this to between 250-500.

> *prepStmtCacheSqlLimit*
> This is the maximum length of a prepared SQL statement that the driver will cache. The MySQL default is 256. In our experience, especially with ORM frameworks like Hibernate, this default is well below the threshold of generated statement lengths. Our recommended setting is 2048.